# Why can't we have static outer classes

Tags: java, static

Why can't we create static classes which are outer. I read answers to the question in this community but I haven't gotten a perfect answer. Can some help me with an exact answer

```
   static class A
    {  
        void display()
        {
            System.out.println("This is a static class");  
        }

    }
```

Comment: because static class in outer level of java is senseless. what do you expect from outer static class that it doesn't have?

Comment: I don't suffer from the lack of such thing in Java.

Comment: Because outer classes are static by them-selves, and you can't define a non-static outer class. So it will be useless to have `static` modifier for outer classes.

Comment: I feel your pain - to my mind it would make sense to have a `static` class implying that all methods and all sub-classes are `static`, just like with a `final` class.

Comment: A "static" method or field is not addressed by an instance, but is directly tied to the class.  Similarly, a "static" (inner) class has instances that are not tied to instances of the containing class (for the purpose of addressing members of the containing scope) but rather are directly tied to the containing class.  The concept is meaningless when applied to an outer class, since there is no "containing" scope to link to.  The term *would not* imply that all members of the class are `static` -- that is not the case for static inner classes and should not be for outer ones.

Comment: Please read the answer to your question, Why can't a Java class be declared as static? on http://stackoverflow.com/a/40015089/2078093

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Outer classes are already effectively `static`  A `static` nested class means it has no reference to the outer class.  An outer class already has no implicit reference to another class.

Comment: Can we find trace of a revived class in a statick block? Does java have a list containing alive classes/class names/types ?

Comment: You can get the enclosing class whether it is static or not.  A nested non-static class also has a reference to an instance of the outer class.

Comment: @Peter I can't get the sentence 'Outer classes are already effectively static'

Comment: I correct you: `static` nested class means it has no reference to the outer class instances (objects). Because an inner class can be static as long as it directly access outer class static members, or members of its fields, or local variables.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly would a static class do? Would it be the "Exact same implementation across all instances"? Think about it :)

Comment: You mean static class has same implementation for every instance created any where.

Comment: Exactly, _Any_ java class has the same implementation for every instance of it created any where, so essentially, outer classes are all static classes! :)

Comment: A bit uncorrect it seems. Static refers to a single copy of memory available for the variables or methods. How can it be a part of implementation and how can outer classes are all static classes.

Comment: There can only be a single definition for any given class, hence it is 'static'. There can be multiple instantiations on a [static] class definition. The [static] single implementation definition is stored in the permgen area of the Java memory space (pre JEP 122).

Comment: A class definition can have 'static variables' or 'class variables' that are a single shared copy of memory available as you said. Indeed as you said, Java's definition differs slightly than C/C++, but it is well defined.

Comment: Can I get a straightforward answer to this question: 'Why cant we have a static class' I don't mean nested classes anywhere

Comment: I can try, I wish I had a whiteboard haha... 'Why can't we have a static class?': You already have them, all outer classes already act like static classes. What behavior are you desiring that's different than how they work? Maybe we can steer you in the right direction. Are you wanting all fields in the class to automatically be static?

Answer (score 1):

Because this is pointless and useless. If you want to have static object, just make static instance of class. And if you want to invoke class methods without reference to it's object, just make this method static. And then you will have:

```
class A
{  
   public static void display()
   {
      System.out.println("This is a static method");  
   }
}
```

You can invoke this method by `A.display();`.

Comment: Can you explain 'pointless and useless' in simple terms.

Comment: If you want to use it's functionality, just make static obiect of this class.

Answer (score 1):

A *static nested class* is simply namespaces at work. The nested class is name-scoped within the *enclosing* class and you can think of the *outer* class as being already present at root *namespace* of that package.

Hence, no `static` keyword is required since the class is already global within the *package* and through-out the application if *public*.

Comment: Can I say like this. For static classes a single copy of heap is alloted where every instance created is allocated in the same single heap which decreases performance of the application. Its just a thought. May be complete invalid

Comment: Not sure what your exact train of thought is but a static nested class gets no special treatment at compile or run-time (except for the package-like namespace). The compiler creates a separate `.class` file just like it would have if the class had been defined on its own. Hence, the JVM would create a separate `Class` object instance for it too. So, it's no different than two classes one defined inside a package and the other not.

Comment: Please don't go for nested classes. I meant completely on Outer classes

Comment: But, outer classes are not static. Or, in other words (if you were to consider them "static"), they're all treated the same. So, I'm still unsure on what you mean with, "for static classes a single copy of heap is alloted".

Comment: As an object is stored in heap, every different instance of class, a heap is allocated. Same as static variables and static methods which are provided a single location in memory, a static classes when instantiated anywhere has a single heap space

Comment: Think of heap as something global; an address space. So, for every object instance of a class, some heap memory is allocated (instead of thinking "a copy of heap is alloted"). The class itself would also be allocated some heap memory for its `Class` object (the one you get from `Class.forName()`); whether it's static or not is immaterial. That goes for its object instances as well. For example, while iterating a `Map` you get static nested `Map.Entry` class objects; all alocated on the heap.

Comment: The heap concept is cleared to me. But a straightforward answer to the question remains.

Answer (score 0):

There are no outer static classes in Java.
Because all outer classes are already visible like the static modifier would do.

But of you mean, that you don't want to need an instance of the class you can simply make all Methods and variables in the class static.