# How can I use ProgressDialog in a static class

Tags: android, static, progressdialog

I have created an AsyncTask and I set it as static like this

```
public static class CreateLiveEventTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventData>>
```

Now I want to add a ProgressDialog to onPreExecute() , so I write some code like this

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null,
                getResources().getText(R.string.loadingEvents), true);
```

But it results in error and said that I need to change AsyncTask to not static . I need this AsyncTask at the other Activity , how can I do to solve this ?

Comment: Remove static from asyncTask.Create object of your class and try to access the CreateLiveEventTask this should be fine to work.

Comment: change to : ProgressDialog.show(CreateLiveEventTask .this

Comment: Use singleton class to avoid this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

Can not create outer class as Static in java

[Why can't we have static outer classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036458/why-cant-we-have-static-outer-classes)
This is reference link

Comment: Yes, All top-level classes are, by definition, static.

Answer (score -1):

Change AsyncTask to non static, & your can create an object of the class containing "CreateLiveEventTask" in the other activity to access CreateLiveEventTask.

Hope it'll help