# How object creation or constructors called implicitly in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I'm little confused about `static methods` and object creation in java.

As we know we can access static members in static method as here.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
// only static method from outside ( without any object )
}
```

But my stupid question is that why java allow this?

```
`public static void main(String[] args){
    Object o = new Object(); // is constructor implicitly static? 
                          // I'm sure no but why java allow this to call here?
    }
```

I know the above statement is similar to declare local variable in static method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 int a = 3;
}
```

But I'm little confused about constructor.

Comment: The `new` operator creates the object before calling the constructor for that object. Hence the constructor is executed on an existing object, not statically on any class.

Comment: @AndreasFester then why mostly people say we are calling constructor by this `new Object();`

Comment: But that is what I said - you can treat the object creation as a two step process which is performed by `new`. See the answer from @PeterLawrey.

Comment: @LetDoit it is called the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bytecode, your `main()` method looks like this (result of the `javap -c Main.class` command):

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #3                  // class java/lang/Object
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: return
```

As you can see, at location 0, the `new` instruction is performed. Then, at location 4, the constructor is invoked on the newly created object.

This is also specified in the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.4):

> **4.10.2.4. Instance Initialization Methods and Newly Created Objects**
>
> Creating a new class instance is a multistep process. The statement:
>
> ```
> ...
> new myClass(i, j, k);
> ...
> ```
>
> can be implemented by the following:
>
> ```
> ...
> new #1            // Allocate uninitialized space for myClass
> dup               // Duplicate object on the operand stack
> iload_1           // Push i
> iload_2           // Push j
> iload_3           // Push k
> invokespecial #5  // Invoke myClass.<init>
> ...
> ```

Comment: You can also see the constructor has the internal signature `<init>` with a return type of `void`. +1

Comment: @LetDoit Use `javap -c -v` Most IDEs have a byte code viewer.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are not static. They are called on the instance, you just created.  In byte code what happens.

1. An new object is created, but it is not inilialised.
2. The constructor is called on that object. In the constructor `this` is the object being initialised.

Comment: `An new object is created, but it is not inilialised.` In byte code? Object already created? or when we call `new` ?

Comment: yes, no, yes.  When we use `new` it creates a new object, after the object is created, it is initialised in the constructor.

Comment: are outer classes implicitly static?

Comment: @LetDoit outer classes implicitly have no even-more-outer class to be an inner class of.

Comment: Then don't know why people give +4 to this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18738063/2769917 Where he clearly mentioned. that `An outer class is already implicitly static.`

Comment: @LetDoit that is one way of explaining it. Top level classes existed before nested classes, and top level classes never need to explain why they were not nested, as there was no other option.